# YA novel about a backyard where shadows live, a dolphin statue/fountain? is the ruler

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read this story in the mid 1980's.  A young boy is staying with either his grandmother, aunt, some older female care giver.  The shadows in the backyard are alive, and anything brought back there that throws a shadow creates a shadow object or individual.  I forget what the conflict is, I think there's some kind of evil ruler of the shadow people.

Either a dolphin statue or fountain rules there.  This book was awesome but I can't remember the title.  I've done several searches online and have turned up nothing.  Any information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The Shades](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060206446) by Betty Brock, seems like it.

> After Hollis washes his eyes in the dolphin fountain, he is able to see a special world whose inhabitants are the shadows of those people that have entered the garden of the house he is visiting.

Comment: Of Course! @Alisha Allston, hopefully you can repay the favor by answering a few other people's questions. :)